# shell commands in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, shell, c#-to-vb.net

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "calc";
        p.Start();
```

for exp. this the code that i use to open calculator
but how can i use , appminimize, maximize, apphide, normal, show  etc. command that i can use in visual basic ? 
Sorry if i had make about tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ProcessStartInfo` to specify a window style. I have tried doing that with `calc.exe`, but that does not work. For other executables e.g. `sol.exe` it's ok.

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("sol.exe");
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();
```

Note that if you create a shortcut to `calc` and set the window style in the properties of the shortcut that does not work either. Maybe the executable sets it's own window style after being started.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
p.EnableRaisingEvents = False
p.StartInfo.FileName = "calc"
p.Start()
```

is the simplest conversion from C# to VB.